# Having issues writing unit test for an endpoint that uses a service, how to write it correctly?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I did not write the endpoint or the service. I am needing to use this endpoint for an application I am building and I was asked to write a unit test on it. I'm having some issues correctly writing the test. Here is what I have so far in my test:

```
public void GetExceptionReportSessionData_ReturnsSessionData()
        {
            //Arrange 
            var response = new RetrieveExceptionReportSessionDatesResponse();
            var serviceClient = new Mock<WorkflowService.WorkflowService>();      
            serviceClient
                .Setup(x => x.RetrieveExceptionReportSessionDatesAsync(It.IsAny<RetrieveExceptionReportSessionDatesRequest>()))
               .ReturnsAsync(response);

            var loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger>();
            loggerMock.Setup(x => x.LogInfo(null));

            var controller = new ExceptionReportController(loggerMock.Object);

            var ctx = new ControllerContext() { HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext() };
            ctx.HttpContext.Request.Headers["token"] = "fake_token_here"; //Set header
            controller.ControllerContext = ctx;

            //Act
            var result = controller.GetExceptionReportSessionData();

            //Assert
            var viewResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);

            Assert.Equal(StatusCodes.Status200OK, viewResult.StatusCode);

        }
```

Here is the endpoint logic:

```
RetrieveExceptionReportSessionDatesResponse response
                = await ResolveServiceClient().RetrieveExceptionReportSessionDatesAsync(new RetrieveExceptionReportSessionDatesRequest());

            List<ExceptionReportSessionDataModel> result
                = GetSessionData(response.RetrieveExceptionReportSessionDatesResult);

            if (result != null && result.Count > 0)
            {
                logText = LogFormatter.Format(
                                WebUtilities.GetUser((ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.User.Identity),
                                startTime, DateTime.Now, Privilege.EditSession,
                                "Get Exception Report Session Data", "Exception Report Session Data retrieved successfully.");
                logger.LogInfo(logText);
            }
            else
            {
                logText = LogFormatter.Format(
                                WebUtilities.GetUser((ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.User.Identity),
                                startTime, DateTime.Now, Privilege.ViewOrderExceptionReport,
                                "Get exception report session data", "Exception report session data is null or empty.");
                logger.LogWarn(logText);
            }
            return Ok(result);
```

Here is the GetSessionData method called in the endpoint:

```
private List<ExceptionReportSessionDataModel> GetSessionData(string sessionData)
    {
        List<ExceptionReportSessionDataModel> reports = new List<ExceptionReportSessionDataModel>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sessionData))
        {
            string[] splitString = sessionData.Split("\n", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach (string s in splitString)
            {
                string[] temp = s.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                List<string> files = new List<string>();

                for (int index = 1; index < temp.Length; index++)
                {
                    files.Add(temp[index]);
                }
                reports.Add(new ExceptionReportSessionDataModel()
                {
                    ReportFiles = files,
                    SessionName = temp[0]
                });
            }
        }
        return reports;
    }
```

How do I finish writing a successful test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not provided definition of `ResolveServiceClient()` method.

Follow below steps to write a Unit Test.

1. Learn Unit Testing. No jokes here. Before writing any unit test you need to have some understanding of how it works and why to write them. Understanding of SOLID principles would help in this process.
2. Analyze the SUT or the method you are testing and list down all the dependencies. **External Dependencies** are classes that perform some tasks for your method. You are testing current method so, everything that does not belong to your class needs to be **decoupled**. In other words, you cannot Unit test a class which calls static methods and initializes external dependencies in the method code. Here, in your code `LogFormatter` and `WebUtilities` seems like they are static classes.
3. Analyze the method and note down all the **exit points**. For e.g. return statements, exceptions, etc. You have to write at least **one unit test for each exit** statement.
4. Analyze the method and note down all the if-else conditions. You have to write a unit test for **each condition**.

Apart from all the theory, your controller seems like a simple case. 
Here, if the `LogFormatter` does not throw any error then you **don't have to decouple** it.
But the `WebUtility` seems problematic. So, I would suggest **creating a service** for it and injecting it in the controller so that you can pass **Mock or Stub** of it from the Unit test.

There is nothing problematic in the `GetSessions()` method just write cases for **each condition** and you will be good to go.

One little tip here, I try to keep the controllers as light as possible. Generally, my controllers are just converting the DTO to service DTO and calling the service. So I don't write unit tests for controllers. But I am not sure everybody does this.